# How to find the maximizer in the Legendre transform of cumulant generating function?

Tags: optimization

Cramer's theorem in the large deviations theory gives the rate function $\sup_{\boldsymbol{\lambda}} \left<\boldsymbol{\lambda},\,\mathbf{b}\right>-\log\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \exp(\left<\boldsymbol{\lambda},\,\mathbf{x}\right>)\,P(dx)$, which is the Legendre transform of $P$'s cumulant generating function.

My problem is how to find the argmax's in the above expression if $P$ is so complicated, such as constructed using Archimedean copulas, that differentiation is almost impossible? Either closed or numerical forms is accepted.

I need this maximizer to solve the minimizer of relative entropy under equality constraint, cf. Altun & Smola, 2006, *Unifying divergence minimization and statistical inference via convex duality*.

I've searched for R and MATLAB functions capable of dealing with this kind of problem, with no useful results.